# Derived default for @Input in Angular

Tags: angular

Here is what I *want* to do:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-something',
  template: `
    <p>${derivedLabel}</p>
  `
})
export class SomethingComponent {

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() derivedLabel = `Select ${this.label}`; // this line does not work
    
}
```

which is illegal (obviously).

What's the "right" way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Should I just take in two inputs and then call a function in the template to get `derivedLabel` if it's defined else return the default string based on `label`? Or is there a more correct/Angular way to do this?

I know because of the component lifecycle this is a little more involved than just setting a variable.

Requirements:

- The developer using the component **must** supply `label`.
- Allow the developer to choose not to supply `derivedLabel`. If `derivedLabel` is not defined, use the text `"Select " + label`. Otherwise, use the supplied `derivedLabel`.

Comment: `@Input() label = '';`?

Comment: While I like the simplicity of this, it removes the requirement by the API for the developer to supply a `label`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for suggestion in my question:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-something',
  template: `
    <p>${derivedLabel()}</p>
  `
})
export class SomethingComponent {

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() actualLabel: string;

  derivedLabel() {
    return actualLabel || `Select ${label}`;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Calling a function in the template? This is your solution? That will run every time change detection fires, which is a lot.

Comment: @R.Richards I didn't say it's a good solution -- which is the whole reason I'm posting here. Because I don't like what I came up with and think there should be a better way to do it! :)

Comment: @R.Richards and to be fair, I don't think change detection will fire too often; it should only fire if the inputs to this component change, which should be never after it's created. I'm no lifecycle expert, though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. CD will fire just about once a second unless you are using an OnPush change detection strategy. https://angular.io/guide/glossary#change-detection

Comment: @R.Richards I just tested it, and you're correct: the function is called more often than I'd like. I might just have to initialize the `label` like you mentioned and assume devs will remember to supply the input even though it's not required.

Comment: @R.Richards I guess it's ultimately a trade-off. Your solution doesn't meet my requirements for a strict component API, and my solution is slow. Pick your poison. Unless there is a better way than either...

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-something',
  template: `
    <p>${derivedLabel}</p>
  `
})
export class SomethingComponent {

  @Input() label: string;
  get derivedLabel(){
    return this.label ? `Select ${this.label}`: 'Select'
  }
    
}
```

Comment: This answer removes the ability for the developer to override `derivedLabel` when using the component.